# typo3 awstats extension after upgrade changes hash for the upload folder

Tags: hash, typo3, awstats

I am facing some problems with cc_awstats extension.

I have upgraded my site to typo3 4.5 from typo3 4.3
After upgrading, awstats file in uploads/tx_ccawstats has changed the hash generated and stored the new log data in newly generated folder.

Before upgrade: folder was "\uploads\tx_ccawstats\my_domain_f0ea6d30"

After upgrade: folder was "\uploads\tx_ccawstats\my_domain_db774c72"

OK, here i edit my question..

what might be the reason for hash change?

domain, logfile absolute path, log file name - these parameters are exactly same

Comment: any suggessions or workaround????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem with awstats extension. The extension which was used on all sites was old version in which once database record is written and folder is created in uploads, it was not updated according to hash. After upgrading the extension, but it was crosschecked and updated in coding with its correct value. I have upgraded the awstats extensions on all sites and imported the old data again for awstats reports.

Comment: Good to know the solution was quite near.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any sign of hash generation in the localconf.php file at the

`$TYPO3_CONF_VARS["FE"]["logfile_dir"]` setting?

I think if you merge the logfiles and reset the logfile directory manually in localconf.php, it should work fine.